# How do I open a locked path?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

I've come across a "locked path" marked with a red padlock. All the keys available in the store seem to be for opening chests. How do I unlock a locked path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you progress through the game and defeat different bosses, you will earn the keys to unlock the padlocks.

Comment: It's an answer, but it would be a lot better if you could elaborate a bit.

Comment: From what I can tell, no actual keys are earned or required to open these paths. Instead, when you beat certain major bosses, you'll see a cutscene where your character shoves his hand in a glowy red magical hole (no, really). You then start a new bloodline and one or more locked paths will be opened.

Comment: @sjohnston "glowy red magical hole" - nice!

Comment: it's also worth noting that each time you defeat the God King and start over, paths that we're previously unlocked will need to be unlocked again in the new play through

Answer (score 0):

Beat the God king. After you beat him I think you unlock all paths.

Answer (score 0):

The answer about defeating "different bosses" is incorrect. You just need to defeat Thane the first time to unlock **all** the locked paths. These locked paths take you to

- Bog giant + Moss Golem (defeat them to get the Vile blade)
- Dark Fiend (defeat it to get the Vile Shield). You also need the Infinity Blade to unlock the tomb.
- Gargap (defeat it to get the Vile Armor). You'll have to go through a few bloodlines for the tree to grow.
- The Blood sentinels (Archivist, Stone Demon and MX Goliath)

in addition to a host of smaller Titans. After unlocking, you'll also be able to get the Vile Helm (need Crown map) and the Holy band (need all other Vile equipment + Vile map).