# How can I proceed down the locked path from the dragon-fountain?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I open a locked path?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39595/how-do-i-open-a-locked-path)

How do I proceed from the room with the dragon fountain?

This is actually the first time I've seen a locked path. I bought some keys for $2,500 but they didn't work. Now I have no money. What should I do?